# Custom bootstrapper from Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper, what is Bootstrapper<IContract> for?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have derived a custom bootstrapper from Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper, I notice it can take a generic type parameter - what is this for?

```
public class SimpleInjectorBootstrapper : Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper
{
    private Container container;

    public SimpleInjectorBootstrapper()
    {
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.container = new Container();
        this.container.Register<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        this.container.Register<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        this.container.Register<IAppViewModel, AppViewModel>();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        return this.container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(sender, e);
        var appViewModel = this.container.GetInstance<IAppViewModel>();
        var windowManager = this.container.GetInstance<IWindowManager>();
        windowManager.ShowWindow(appViewModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a view model type to use as your starting view model. Caliburn.Micro will resolve the type from the IoC container, and in WPF use the `WindowManager` to display the root view. Bascially what you're doing in your `OnStartup` override.